# NSURLSession bandwidth limiting

Tags: macos, nsurlsession, bandwidth-throttling

Is there a way to limit the bandwidth in **NSURLSession**?

I'm making file-sync-client for macOS like `Dropbox/GoogleDrive/pCloud` and they all have bandwidth limiting options, but I'm not sure how to configure **NSURLSession** to respect bandwidth limiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [ASIHTTPRequest](https://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest) features `Bandwidth throttling support`. Although it may be an old library, from what I observe it's still fully functional thus it may be worth exploring.

Of course, using `ASIHTTPRequest` would require abandoning `NSURLSession` for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Unless Apple has added something very recently, NSURLSession provides no facilities for bandwidth limiting.  The only ways I'm aware of to do that are:

- Use lower-level APIs that allow you to provide your own sockets and then throttle the data rate at the TCP socket level.
- Provide an in-app web proxy and use it for all outgoing requests.  Configure the proxy to limit the bandwidth of all requests that go through it.

Comment: Thanks dgatwood, do you know of any in-app web proxy which could help in this case?

Comment: Hi, following your answer, NSURLSession is using CFNetwork internally, just like the ASIHTTPRequest mentioned in the previous answer. As ASIHTTPRequest supports throttling, maybe there's a way to access the lower level CFNetwork objects from the NSURLSession, and configure them for throttling? do you recon this is possible?

Comment: No.  NSURLSession doesn't expose its CF underpinnings at all.  And in background sessions (which you would probably want to use for something that does large uploads and downloads), the requests aren't even issued within your app's process, so marshalling the CF structures across the process boundaries would likely not work correctly even if you could find a way to access those structures in foreground requests.  This really is a "file an enhancement request" thing.